# How do I fix background and text colors in email from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to allow me to email a section of an excel spreadsheet.  Whenever I use this it sometimes has weird formatting where the background color is black and the introduction text is red.  I'd like to either correct this to plain black on white or force it to plain text.  Setting BodyFormat to the plain text option did not work though.  It looks like it is getting style information from somewhere, but I do not know where or how to change it.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub EmailMessage()

ActiveSheet.Range("E3:F14").Select

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "Message for " + FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now, vbLongDate)
    .Item.To = "someemail@testemail.gov"
    .Item.Subject = "Message for " + FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now, vbShortDate)
    .Item.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you tried without Item.BodyFormat?

Comment: Yes.  I originally did not have the BodyFormat in there.  That was something I tried to add after noticing the problem.  It gave me an unknown error when I tried to use the Plain text option.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem and I manually changed background to white on the selected area and it fixed it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was using this line before emailing the sheet:
`Sheets("toSend").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone`

edit: I'm back, turns out this only fixed it temporarily, now it doesn't work again...  In my situation, I'm copying a sheet to a new sheet then sending it out.  I changed the background color of the sheet I'm copying, to the color white (by right clicking the top left of the sheet then changing the fill color to white).  It now works again!